# Does FPC respect block lifetime?

Tags: magento2.2, full-page-cache, block-cache

Example: FPC lifetime is 1 day but a page contains a block with a lifetime of 1 hour. How will that be handled? Will the page be served from the cache after the hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It did a quick test on it:

- I did set the FPC lifetime to 60 second
- I wrote a block and overrode `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock::getCacheLifetime` to return 30
- Additionally I set `ttl="30"` in layout xml

Without the block the FPC lifetime was 60 seconds as expected. Then I inserted the block on the page and the FPC lifetime was still 60 seconds, the block was unaffected of the given 30 seconds.

Maybe I did set the cache lifetime of the block wrong but it seems like the FPC just ignores any lifetime set in the block.

Comment: I hate that - I think it should work differently.